# Github folder organisation efficiency

Tags: github

I have a very simple question regarding the general organisation of folders in `GitHub`.

Because I often forget to `commit` specific GitHub project, I started to group different projects and folders in large generic folders.

For instance, I would have a general folder called `all_projects`, and put inside `project 1`, `project 2`, and so on. Then I would simply `git add .` everything at once.

As my general folders getting bigger and bigger, I was wondering if there are major drawbacks to this kind of organisation and how you would do it differently.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bad practice to put everything you do in same folder. Not locally, but on Github.

Locally, you can create folder `Programming` or `my_work` or `all_projects` and in there, create projects separately. They also should **have a proper name, not just be named**. For example, if the project is doing web scraping instagram, name it `Instagram web scraper` or `InstagramScraper` or something that when read, almost instantly remember what you did just by reading project(folder) name.

Also, check if the project is large or small.

If this project is something you've built for long, with big project structure and lots of files connected somehow to each other, than you can push it to github with proper name of repo and README.md . It is self contained and it shouldn't be part of some else project that has nothing to do with it.

If small, like one script, or just something you've practiced while learning something, consider using https://gist.github.com . It's connected to your github account and it can hold small scripts.

**P.S.**

*This is my personal opinion*.